# how do I keep nested div's to not "leak" out the bottom?

Tags: css, html, css-float, haml

In haml, I have something like this:

```
#profile
   #photo

   #bio
```

But what hapens is the `#photo` "leaks" out of the `#profile` div.  If I inspect it, `#profile` is a very small box and `#photo` peaks out of it.

I applied a `float:left` to `#photo` so that `#bio` will sit next to the photo

I seem to run into this alot.  What is going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you show or link to some code? Is #photo a <div> or an <img>?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find that the easiest way is to add `overflow:hidden` to the container, `#profile` in your case.

No extra elements needed and no side-effects from clearing left, right or both.

Comment: @Thomas Shields Although it´s an old article, there´s a nice overview here (no real explanation though...): http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: hm, okay. I'm trying to understand why it works, according to the standards and defined behaviors.

Comment: what does overflow:hidden mean?  I thought of trying this but when I looked up the docuentation, I didn't understand how it would relate....

Comment: @Angela Unless you have any elements that are absolutely positioned, the only effect it has is that it reminds the box to be a box.

Answer (score 4):

When you have a container with floats inside, you need some way of telling the container to clear the floats at the bottom.

The usual way of doing this is to create an element in the DOM at the end of the container after all of the floating items and tell it to `clear:left;` whilst also setting it to `visibility:hidden;`
(Assuming your floated items are floating to the `left`, otherwise use `right` or `both` as the `clear` value)

You can do this with pure CSS as:

```
#container:after{
  content:".";
  display:block;
  clear:left;
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

There's always the option of directly adding a HTML element to the bottom of the container however I find the pure CSS way a tad nicer.

Answer (score 4):

[Floated](http://css-tricks.com/795-all-about-floats/) elements do not take up space in their parent container. To fix this, you need to add something below these elements that do not allow the floated elements to float past it. You can accomplish this with the [CSS property `clear`](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_clear.asp). So in your case, add:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

To clear those floated elements from extending past it.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you should just tell the photo not to exceed the box limits, auto resizing:

```
#photo {
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

This way the photo will not exceed the div size. Probably you should also add `position:relative;` to the #profile div.

**Update**

I forgot to specify that this works only if your #photo is actually an image element.

Comment: It's meant to be used with images. Do you know if that #photo element is actually a div or an image?

Comment: aha okay. Could you just specify that in your answer a little more clearly and i'll give you your vote back :P

Comment: Done. Now better wait for more details I guess ;)

Comment: #photo is a div and there is an =image_tag nested inside

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple methods.  I tend to use the older methods such:

Apply `overflow:auto` to the wrapping parent div.

Or placing a div element right before the parent div closing tag that has `clear:both;` applied.

There are new methods, such as using the `:after` pseudo class in css, but I have had problems with that method.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing div:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .clear { height: 0px; line-height: 0px; clear:both; font-size:0px; }
</style>


<div class="profile">
     <div class="photo"><img /></div>
     <div class="bio">Lorem ipsum</div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Should work for all browsers affected.